# C - how to input this line

Tags: c, arrays, string, input, struct

I'm trying to take as input of a struct this kind of line
"1 Myke Tyson 1234567891"

What is the best way to do this?

This is what I tried:

```
scanf("%d", &list.n1);
fgets(list.name, 14, stdin);

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &list.n2[i]);
}
```

EDIT: This is the struct:

```
   struct ex{
         int n1;
         char name[14];
         int n2[10];
   }
```

Comment: Please show the struct declaration. What are you trying to set the final contents of the struct to? Are there really quotes in the input line?

Comment: There's only one number after the name, why are you reading 10 numbers?

Comment: I suspect the OP wants to read each of those 10 digits form this one integer into a different element of `n2[10]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgets()`, `sscanf()` and additional code to parse.

This parsing would be more robust if the separator (a space) was not allowed in a field.  The potential space or spaces within `.name` convoluted the parsing.  Recommend comma separated fields.  Further the `int n2[10]` field is unusual.   Why not `unsigned long long n2`?

Be sure to check result of `fgets()`, `sscanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ex {
  int n1;
  char name[14];
  int n2[10];
} ex;

int ReadEx(ex *dest) {
  char buf[20 + 1 + 14 - 1 + 1 + 10 + 2];  // Or use something big like buf[100]
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL ) {
    return -1;  // EOF or I/O Error
  }

  char name[14 + 1]; // temp place for name and final space separator
  int p1, p2;        // Offset for beginning and end of n2 array
  unsigned long long ull;  // Dummy to save n2 array
  if (3 != sscanf(buf, "%d %14[A-Za-z ]%n%llu%n", 
      &dest->n1, name, &p1, &ull, &p2)) {
    return 1; // format error
  }

  // strlen(name) cannot have the value of 0 here as sscanf() is 3
  size_t SpaceIndex = strlen(name) - 1;
  if ((name[SpaceIndex] != ' ') || ((p2 - p1) != 10)) {
    return 1; // format error, space expected at end of name and 10 digits
  }
  // name cannot contain only spaces due to the space before %14
  while (name[SpaceIndex] == ' ') {
    name[SpaceIndex--] = '\0';
  }
  strcpy(dest->name, name);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    dest->n2[i] = buf[p1 + i] - '0';
  }
  return 0;
  // One could use the below approach but it is not so extensible.
  // if (12 != sscanf(buf, "%d %14[A-Za-z ]%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d %c",
  //   &dest->n1, name, &dest->n2[0], &dest->n2[1], ... &dest->n2[9], &dummychar)) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible way is

```
struct ex{
     int n1;
     char name[14];
     char n2[11];
}

scanf("%d", &list.n1);
fgets(list.name, 14, stdin);
fgets(list.n2, 11, stdin);
```

Comment: Not necessarily. It work perfectly fine for 32bit wide signed integers.

Comment: The value 1234567891 is to be stored in an array of 10 integers.

Comment: @haccks why wasnt it workign with the loop and scanf?

Comment: Why do you think it will work with them. Remember `n2` is declared as `char` array not `char` :). To print it you should use `%s` specifier.

Comment: @haccks n2 is declared as an int array.

Comment: In my answer it is declared `char array` !

Comment: what if the name is less than 14 characters, it will append some numbers to the name

Comment: @Shubham; Most probably it will not.

Comment: I guess the down-vote was because the question has changed and the 10 digits are to be stored in 10 separate entries of an array in the structure.  It really isn't fair to penalize someone when the question changed after their answer was submitted.